# a small amount of money

Tags: meaning, quantifiers

a. I had a small amount of money.

That could mean

1. I had a little money.

but could it also mean

2. I had little money.

?

I think it could.

I think the way the words are emphasized will change the meaning.

a1. I had a small amount of money and couldn't afford to take a taxi.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Saying "I had a small amount of money" is like saying "I had a little money", it contrasts with "I had no money".  So in your example with the taxi, there is a contrast between "I had a small amount of money" and "I couldn't take a taxi", and I would normally link the clauses with "but"

> I had a small amount of money but I couldn't afford to take a taxi.

The version with "and" is not wrong, and would be natural if the first sentence is modified with (for example) "only".

> I only had a small amount of money and I couldn't afford a taxi.

Answer (score 1):

I had a small amount of money.= 1. I had **a little** money. (NOT 2. 'I had *little money*')

Correct: I had **only a little** money and couldn't afford to take a taxi.

Correct: I had a small amount of money **but** I couldn't afford to take a taxi.

There is a difference between **a little** and **little**.

**Little** is rather negative. It is a negative idea. It means 'not much'.
There is little time.(=not much, not enough time)  I have little money(not much/almost nothing) The cactus needs little water. There seems little hope.

A little= some, a small amount.

**A little** is more positive. It means 'some' (but not a lot). We got a little help. Give the roses a little water. I save a little money every month. (=some money, a small amount of money) You still have a little time left. There is little chance of success.

Little is rather formal. In conversation, we prefer 'not much' or **only a little.**

**Only a little** has a negative meaning. We have only a little time.